# Impossible type assertions with casting from interface type to the actual type

Tags: go

I'm getting two errors,

a. Impossible Type assertion. Can we cast from interface type to the actual type object

b. not sure what's the meaning of evaluated but not used

```
type IAnimal interface {
    Speak()
}
type Cat struct{}

func (c *Cat) Speak() {
    fmt.Println("meow")
}



type IZoo interface {
    GetAnimal() IAnimal
}
type Zoo struct {
    animals []IAnimal
}
func (z *Zoo) GetAnimal() IAnimal {
    return z.animals[0]
}
```

Testing

```
var zoo Zoo = Zoo{}

// add a cat
var cat IAnimal = &Cat{}
append(zoo.animals, cat) // error 1: append(zoo.animals, cat) evaluated but not used

// get the cat

var same_cat Cat = zoo.GetAnimal().(Cat) // error 2: impossible type assertions

fmt.Println(same_cat)
```

go [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/qhJ49pf1sU)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

1. The error message pretty much says it all:

   ```
   tmp/sandbox129360726/main.go:42: impossible type assertion:
       Cat does not implement IAnimal (Speak method has pointer receiver)
   ```

   `Cat` does not implement `IAnimal`, because `Speak` (part of the `IAnimal` interface) has a pointer receiver, and `Cat` is not a pointer.

   If you change `Cat` to `*Cat`, it works:

   ```
   var same_cat *Cat = zoo.GetAnimal().(*Cat)
   ```
2. The error pretty much says it all, too.

   ```
    append(zoo.animals, cat)
   ```

   You're appending `cat` to `zoo.animals` (evaluating), then throwing away the result, because there's nothing on the left side.  You probably want to do this instead:

   ```
   zoo.animals = append(zoo.animals, cat)
   ```

One other side note: When you're assigning to a variable directly, there's no need to specify the type, because Go can determine it for you.  Therefore

```
var same_cat Cat = zoo.GetAnimal().(Cat)
```

would be better expressed as:

```
var same_cat = zoo.GetAnimal().(Cat)
```

or also:

```
same_cat := zoo.GetAnimal().(Cat)
```

Comment: thanks. for error 2 I instead change the method signature, removed pointer from speak. https://play.golang.org/p/1fQNj6rrsd is it possible to have the method this way

Comment: Sure, there's no reason that can't work just as well.:)

Comment: sorry didn't get you, it didn't work, https://play.golang.org/p/1fQNj6rrsd

Comment: `var cat IAnimal = &Cat{}` <-- You're still setting `IAnimal` to a pointer, then trying to assert it as a non-pointer. You need to be consistent throughout.

Comment: i see, so if i save pointer, i can only get back pointer, i can't get back actual object?

Comment: You can, but you have to dereference it with `*`. `Cat = *CatPtr`

Comment: hmmm possible to see some playground code from my example, I still didn't get this last part.